# include config.php sitewide using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, include, scope

Is there a way to autoprepend my `config.php` file site-wide specially using `.htaccess` when i place .htaccess file in the site root other subdirectories with .htaccess and autoprepend overwrites the one in the site root is there a way to prevent overwrite and stack them on top of each other?

Answer (score 0):

if php is httpd module, than you can specify in your .htaccess:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file config.php
```

Comment: php is a module and i can auto prepend the problem is i can't access config.php included in the site root using htaccess in other subdirectories

Comment: than you need to specify absolute path to you config.php, i.e. /var/www/somesite/config.php

Comment: i edit the q Ivan directives overwrite each other because of confliction is there a way to prevent that and say add this one on top of the old one? sorry for keep editing q :)

Comment: via .htaccess you setup 1 php variable, that allow you to prepend 1 file http://au.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file, if you need more complex logic, you can set environment variables in .htaccess files, analyse them in config.php, and load needed file via `requre()`